# R: separate a series of string by comma

Tags: r

I have a series of string marked by quotation marks and I'd like them to be separated by comma so that I can pass them to a vector. I tried paste command but I kept getting error messages. Thank you.
The data is like:

```
"Alabama"     "Arkansas"    "Connecticut" "Georgia"     "Hawaii"     "Minnesota"   "Mississippi" "Missouri"    "Oregon"
```

Comment: please share the output of `dput(df)`, Copy/pasting data here does not represent the actual dataset structure. P.S. What do you mean exactly by passing them to a vector? It seems you are going after the wrong solution for what you need ([XY PROBLEM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: This is unclear. Are you trying to split a single string into a vector or are you trying to combine a vector of strings into a single string? In any event, you should post a [mcve] if you want help. Merely telling us that you got an unspecified error when using `paste` in an unknown way to data which has an unknown structure doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: `df <- read.table(text = '<your input here>')`?  As Masoud says, it depends on your data

Answer (score 0):

You can try something as:

```
str <- '"Alabama"     "Arkansas"    "Connecticut" "Georgia"     "Hawaii"     "Minnesota"   
"Mississippi" "Missouri"    "Oregon"'


gsub('\\"',"",gsub('\\"\\s+\\"',",",str))

#[1] "Alabama,Arkansas,Connecticut,Georgia,Hawaii,Minnesota,Mississippi,Missouri,Oregon"
```

**regex:**

- `\\"\\s+\\"`     - Look for multiple spaces within `"` and replace with `","`

Comment: If my regex is correct, you should just be able to use `\s+` and don't need the nesting or the double slashes?

Comment: @Punintended The quotes `"` will still be there. OP wants `"` to be removed as well.

Comment: Ah, misunderstood the original question.  My bad

Comment: @Punintended No worries. I have added explanation of my answer anyway.